# How to loop through a column to copy all matching rows to another sheet using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT#1:
I am trying to loop through a column to find a list of pre-specified numbers and if match is found, copy the entire row to another tab but I am getting error. Could some one please help?

Based on the error that I was getting for my range, I felt that it was because of the way I was getting my samples range, so I changed it but I am still getting it.

**Error:**

**Runtime Error '1004':**

**Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed**

I am getting this error for this line:

```
For Each c In Range(rng)
```

Here's the code:

```
Sub Sampler()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range, c As Range, val As Variant
Dim rng As Variant
Dim answer As Long, lr As Long
Dim ans As Variant
Dim myrange As Variant
Dim leadsheet As Variant

    answer = MsgBox("Does your population have serial number column starting from 1?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Very Important")
    
    If answer = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "Great!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Press Esc. and add the serial number column in the population."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ans = InputBox("Enter tab name for random data", "Sample Selector")
    
    Worksheets(ans).Activate
    
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range for samples", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    MsgBox "The cells selected were " & rng.Address
    leadsheet = InputBox("Enter tab name for population", "Population Tab Finder")
    
    Set ws = Worksheets(leadsheet)
    
    'check each cell in the specific worksheet if the criteria is matching
    For Each c In Range(rng)
        Set myrange = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlUp))
        For Each cell In myrange
            If cell.Value = c Then
                lr = Sheets(ans).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
                cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets(ans).Range("S" & lr + 1)
            End If
        Next cell
    Next

End Sub
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: *I am getting error* Where? What line does arise the error?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I have updated it now.

Comment: Delete the part `.Select`

Comment: Still getting the same error at the same place.

Comment: Make sure the value `leadsheet` is correct

Comment: I rechecked and it is correct. [link]https://imgur.com/a/3EnAD8U[link]

Comment: The value for `rng` is something like `A:A`? Please explain `Range("A1", Range("A1")` in your error statement. It appears that You haven't selected the Range properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the reference `ws` when defining `myrange`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Sampler()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range, c As Range, rngDst As Range
Dim rngSrc As Variant
Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim ans As Variant
Dim myrange As Variant
Dim leadsheet As Variant

    answer = MsgBox("Does your population have serial number column starting from 1?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Very Important")
    
    If answer = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "Great!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Press Esc. and add the serial number column in the population."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ans = InputBox("Enter tab name for random data", "Sample Selector")
    
    Sheets(ans).Activate
    
    Set rngDst = Sheets(ans).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    Set rngSrc = Application.InputBox("Select a range for samples", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    leadsheet = InputBox("Enter tab name for population", "Population Tab Finder")
    
    Set ws = Worksheets(leadsheet)
    
    'check each cell in the specific worksheet if the criteria is matching
    For Each c In rngSrc.Cells
        Set myrange = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        For Each cell In myrange
            If cell.Value = c Then
                cell.EntireRow.Copy rngDst
                Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1)
            End If
        Next cell
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I did that but now I get another error saying: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set for the line: `rng = InputBox("Enter range for random samples", "Sample Selector")`

Comment: I've changed the code to avoid that error.

Comment: That seems to bypass the error that I was getting earlier but now it seems that another error came up: Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed for the line: `For Each c In Range(rng)`

Comment: What is being entered for `rng`?

Comment: rng has the range of the 25 samples that I am trying to find in the population. Here's an image that you can see as well: [https://imgur.com/a/FlDjAFp]

Comment: Yes, but what are you entering when you are prompted for 'Enter range for random samples'?

Comment: Ohh, I'm entering K1:O5 there to specify the range.

Comment: I changed the method to get the range for `rng`. Now I am getting it using my mouse by dragging it across the specified range as I updated in the code at the top. But the error is still the same.

Comment: I've changed the code to allow you to select the range for `rng` rather than entering the address. When you do that you only need `rng` not `Range(rng)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This seems to be working perfectly. The only catch is that it is only pasting the last value it finds and match for and not all the values which match.

Comment: I've updated the code again, let me know if it works properly now.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much @norie! Really appreciate the help! I made a few adjustments into it making it paste in a new sheet which it will create automatically. Thank you so much!